# Reading from input box onblur

Tags: javascript, html, authentication, onblur

I'm trying to build a login page.  I would like to read the information from the username text box to use in javascript with the onblur event.  So ideally, when somebody tabs or clicks away after they've entered their name, the page will read in the name, and use it in a script to display information about that person.  All of this would occur before the password is entered.  Does anybody know of a way to read information from an input box in this manner? Here's what I have so far.

```
//This will display the content
function createDiv()
{
var divTag = document.createElement("div");
divTag.style.position = "absolute";
divTag.style.top = "95px";
divTag.style.left = "426px";
divTag.style.zIndex = "20";
divTag.innerHTML = "MSS";
document.getElementById('card').appendChild(divTag);
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload='init();'>

<div id="card" style="width:800px; z-index:10; height:600px; position:relative; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; text-align:center; margin-top:0px; background-image:url('customLoginBG.png'); background-repeat:no-repeat;">
<form method='post' action='/login'>
<ul style="list-style-type:none;">
<li> <input type='hidden' id='token' name='token' /> </li>

<!-- After tabbing away from here, I display content. -->
<li style="position:absolute; top:270px; left:260px;"> <input type='text' onblur="createDiv()" id='username' style="width:188px; height:26px; outline: none; border: none; border-color:transparent; background-image:url('inputBar.png'); " /> </li>

<li style="position:absolute; top:310px; left:260px;"> <input type='password' id='password' style="width:188px; height:26px; outline: none; border: none; border-color:transparent; background-image:url('inputBar.png'); " /> </li>
<li style="position:absolute; top:290px; left:455px;"> <input type='image' src="loginButton.png" value="Login" onclick='doLogin();' /> </li>      

</ul>  
</form>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far.  We don't mind helping people finish code, but most of us don't just "create from scratch."

Answer (score 1):

With jquery (1.7 or later) you just do

```
$("#inputboxname").on("blur", function () {
    var value = $(this).val();
    // Do stuff with value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('input').blur(function() {
     console.log($(this).val());
}`

Answer (score 0):

You could assign the [`onblur`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.onblur) event handler to the input:

```
<input id="username" type="text" />

​document.getElementById("username").onblur = function () {
  var name = this.value;
  // do something with it
};​​​
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('txtbox1').onblur = function(){
     alert(this.value);
}​​​​​​
```

However if your going to be doing a lot of javascript stuff, i'd learn to use the jQuery library, makes so many things far simplier. But understanding the basic of standard javascript is a must.